# Fiware Health region configuration

Tags: openstack, fiware, keystone, fiware-health

I'm studying about [FIWARE Health - Sanity Checks](https://github.com/Fiware/ops.Health/blob/master/fiware-region-sanity-tests/README.rst), and some configuration is needed before test execution (Sanity Checks execution). To run the Sanity Checks, I need edit the configuration file, [etc/settings.json](https://github.com/Fiware/ops.Health/blob/master/fiware-region-sanity-tests/etc/settings.json).

But I don't understand the information that I need to give in region_configuration. I created some regions in my keystone, but I don't know how get the external_network_name, and shared_network_name.

Answer (score 0):

How do you say, there are 3 parameters that you have to keep into consideration:

- external_network_name, it contains the network that it really
  connected to internet. It means that you should be configured with
  neutron this network with the following values:

  - provider:physical_network = external
  - router:external = true
  - shared = false
- shared_network_name, this is a network that we have created in FIWARE to be used by all tenants (projects). It means that you should be configured with neutron this network with the following values:

  - provider:physical_network = (no value)
  - router:external = false
  - shared = true
  - test_object_storage, this paremeter is used to specify if you want to check the Object Storage functionality.

I think that if you create those networks in the region you can use without problems in your OpenStack instance.